# Nginx redirect from old subdomain to new subdomain

Tags: nginx, http-redirect

I want to redirect all traffic from old subdomain to new subdomain but something went wrong =)

Here is my config:

```
# Redirect from http to https
server {
  listen 80 default deferred; # for Linux
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Redirect section - from old to new sub
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  server_name old.domain.com www.old.domain.com;
  return 301 https://new.domain.com$request_uri;

  # should I use SSL while redirecting? without old certs nginx gives me an error...
  ssl_certificate ...
  ...
}

# main working subdomain
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name new.domain.com www.new.domain.com;
  root ...
  ...
}
```

With this config I can access to `new.domain.com` and it is working as expected with valid SSL cert, but old `old.domain.com` is also accessible without redirection :(

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. It is better suited to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that the configuration is correct as shown in your question. You must clear the browser's cache and restart Nginx between configuration changes. Or use `curl -I` to test the responses from the server.

Answer (score 0):

My variant is working, it was an error on DNS provider side (something was wrong with DNS records, CNAME)